# Batch - get content between two strings

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have string like this

```
 <AdaptationSet maxHeight="576" maxWidth="1024" mimeType="video/mp4" id="0" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
  <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" cenc:default_KID="bcf950eb-a062-5b0d-b1f2-fed53f20ba10">
    <cenc:pssh>AAAATHBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAACwiJGFlNWU5NTk4LWU5ODktNWM1Ny1iOTk2LTg3OTA4NWIyYzUxNUjj3JWbBg==</cenc:pssh>
  </ContentProtection>
  <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="bcf950eb-a062-5b0d-b1f2-fed53f20ba10" />
  <SegmentTemplate duration="6000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/video/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$_184201/segment_$Number$.m4s" startNumber="0" timescale="1000" />
  <Representation bandwidth="247600" codecs="avc1.64001F" height="144" width="256" id="ae5e9598-e989-5c57-b996-879085b2c515-0_video_frag_auto.idx~video_frag_auto~481" scanType="progressive" />
```

I want to get output like below and put it into a variable.

```
ae5e9598-e989-5c57-b996-879085b2c515
```

Note that there is already `id="0"` in the first line and I want to extract value of id partially for the last line.
Is there an easy way to do this in batch?

Comment: Is it possible to specify generically what it is about "-0_video_frag_auto.idx~video_frag_auto~481" you're not interested in? For example, are you not interested in anything after first five blocks separated by "-"?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use batch, here's one example to get started. This extracts all values id from file ooo.txt that contains your string.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=0
for /f "eol=> tokens=* usebackq delims= " %%i in (`type ooo.txt`) do (
  set x=0
  set XXX=XXX
  for %%I in (%%i) do (
    if "%%I"=="id" (
      set x=1
    ) else (
      if !x! EQU 1 (
        set x=0
        set XXX=%%I
      )
    )
  )
  set XXX=!XXX:"=!
  if not "!XXX!"=="XXX" (
    set XXX=!XXX:"=!
    rem echo !XXX!
    call :enumerate !XXX! YYY
    echo !YYY!
  )
)

goto :eof

:enumerate
set pos=0
set Y=%1
set result=
set part=
:countchar
if not "!Y:~%pos%,1!"=="" (
  set /a pos=pos+1
  if "!Y:~%pos%,1!"=="-" (
    set result=!result!!part!
    set part=
  )
  set part=!part!!Y:~%pos%,1!
  goto :countchar
)
set %~2=!result!
exit/b
:eof
endlocal
```

This outputs

```
ae5e9598-e989-5c57-b996-879085b2c515
```

and, within the loop, stores each id in variable `YYY` (although the first one is empty).

This assumes you want to keep everything up to but not including the last hyphen `-`.

Comment: But for the second value i just want to extract ae5e9598-e989-5c57-b996-879085b2c515 and not the whole value.

Comment: Is it possible to specify generically what it is about "-0_video_frag_auto.idx~video_frag_auto~481" you're not interested in? For example, are you not interested in anything after first five blocks separated by "-"? Or, is there never a hyphen `-` in the string you're not interested in? (thus, everything after last `-` inclusive can be removed)

Comment: Or, is the string you're interested in always the same number of characters? i.e. 36

Comment: @user8333491 Please see update to answer. It outputs what you request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'for fun' example, which, as you've provided no code yourself, will not be modified post answer, and no support, or explanation, will be undertaken either.

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /i "id=\"[a-e0123456789]*-[a-e0123456789]*-[a-e0123456789]*-[a-e0123456789]*-[a-e0123456789]*-" "xmlfile.mpd"'
) Do @Set "}=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F UseBackTokens^=2-6Delims^=-^" %%H In ('!}:* id^=^"^=!') Do @Endlocal & Set "id=%%H-%%I-%%J-%%K-%%L"
@(Set id) 2>NUL & Pause
```

You will probably want to change the source filename from `xmlfile.mpd`, and can optionally remove the last line, which was included just to allow you to see if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65892027.txt"

SET "capture="
SET "captured="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR %%c IN (%%b) DO (
  IF /i "%%~c"=="scantype" SET "capture="&IF DEFINED captured GOTO done
  IF DEFINED capture SET "captured=%%~c"
  IF /i "%%~c"=="id" SET "capture=Y"
 )
)
:done
ECHO captured "%captured%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo:
set "td=%~dp0"
set "pattern= id="
set "id=id"
call:getPatternLength "!id!" plen
set /a "slen=!plen!-1"
set "opt=tokens=1,2,* delims=<"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%z in (' type "!td!usedata\id.txt"^| findstr /c:"!pattern!" ') do (
   for /f "%opt%" %%b in ("%%z") do (
      for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%y in ('echo/%%b^|findstr /v [0-9][a-z]') do (
         set "bempty=true"
         call:findit "%%c" "!id!" strfound
      )
      if not defined bempty call:findit "%%b" "!id!" strfound
      set "strfound=!strfound:"=!"
      if defined strfound (
         call:handlefound "!strfound!" result
         if defined result (echo Finally: !result! & exit /b 0)
      )
   )
)

:end
endlocal
exit /b 0



:getPatternLength
set "str=%~1"
set /a "count=0"
:next
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%z in ('echo/!str!') do (
   set /a "count+=1"
   set "str=!str:~1!"
   if not "!str!"=="" goto:next
)
set "%2=!count!"
if /i "%0"==":getPatternLength" (exit /b 0)


:handlefound
set "str=%~1"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('echo/!str!^| findstr [a-z]') do (
   :notyet
   for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=-" %%d in ("!str!") do (
      for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g in ('echo/%%e^|findstr "_"') do (
         set "res=!res!-%%d"
         set "%2=!res!"
         exit /b 0
      )
      if not defined res ( set "res=%%d" ) else ( set "res=!res!-%%d")
      set "str=%%e-%%f" & goto:notyet
   )
)
echo Not the right line.. next.
exit /b 1


:findit
set "str=%~1"
set "find=%~2"
set "opts=tokens=1,* delims= "
set "opts2=tokens=1,* delims=="

:nexttoken
for /f "%opts%" %%m in ("!str!") do (
   for /f "%opts2%" %%o in ("%%m") do (
      if "%%o"=="!find!" (
         set "%3=%%p"
         if "%0"==":findit" exit /b 0
      )
      set "str=%%n" & goto:nexttoken
   )
)
exit /b 1
```